# On Ajax Load Btn Click Set Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I load an ajax query via two dates on my page which displays a list of calls.

Within the data returned there is CallID, Name, Date, Button to Complete.

I can't seem to get my javascript to fire on the button click after the AJAX call.

First my HTML:

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control date-picker" id="startdate" value="<?php echo date("m/d/Y");?>">

    <input type="text" class="form-control date-picker" id="enddate" value="<?php echo date("m/d/Y");?>">

<input type"text" id="rep" value="WOLRAB">

    <div id="calls"></div>
```

Second my AJAX to call data:

```
$('input#daterange').on('click', function() {

        var start = $('input#startdate').val();
        var end = $('input#enddate').val();
        var rep = $('input#rep').val();

        $.post('assets/ajax/repscalls.php', {startdate: start,enddate: end, rep:rep}, function(data) {
            $('#calls').html(data)
        });

});
```

Thirdly my php file performing results (note I've only copied in the button that displays on html page after ajax fire.

```
echo "<td><input type='hidden' id='callid' value='" . $row['callid'] . " '><input type='submit' id='completecall' value='Complete'></td>";
```

Now once this has been outputted to HTML page, I then want to click the COMPLETE button which updates that call with the status complete.

I was doing this a similar way, but for some reason I can't get my javascript to fire on button click.

```
$('input#completecall').on('click', function() {
        var completeid = $('input#callid').val();
        alert(completeid);  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing about AJAX is that JavaScript will not wait until the AJAX call is complete before executing code preceding it. E.g:

```
#some ajax call takes 10 seconds here`
var x = 2 + 2;
#ajax call complete
```

x will be evaluated instantly, not waiting for the AJAX call.

You will need to utilise the `complete` function of the AJAX call to ensure the button is clicked as you wish. E.g:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "test.php",
  data: "whatever",
  success: function(data){
     // do whatever 
  },
  complete: function(){ 
    // do your click
  }
});
```

`complete` always gets called, regardless of if an error/success occurs

---

Info on jQuery AJAX call here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use event delegate to listen to events which target is added after the register action.

`$('input#completecall')` probably has nothing when you call it, as it's not returned from server and not added to page yet, so your `$('input#completecall').on('click',` registered to nothing.

What you should do is find the container for that newly added element, and use the delegate form of [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) to register the event.

So you can write your code like:

```
$('#calls').on('click', 'input#completecall', function() {
        var completeid = $('input#callid').val();
        alert(completeid);  
})
```

Below is a demo:

```js
$('#add').click(function() {
  if ($('#new').length === 0) {
    var div = $('<div>').text('New one').attr('id', 'new').appendTo('#calls');
  }
});

$('#new').on('click', function() {
  alert("I won't be triggered!");
});

$(document).on('click', '#new', function() {
  alert("I will be triggered!");
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="add">Add</div>
<div id="calls"></div>
```